# What does this.ngIf in an Angular directive's controller do?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got a controller function set in `directive's` `return` statement like this: `controller: elementCtrl`.

Inside this function I've got a weird (simplified) example where `ct.ngIf = false;` is set.

```
function elementCtrl($scope, $element) {
    var ct = this;

    $document.on('click', function() {
        ct.ngIf = false;
    });
}
```

Directive is `Element` type and on directive `ng-if` is applied. But the problem is that I do not understand what is this and how it works, and couldn't find any doc example of that usage.

And what's more, is it possible for me to use other Angular core directives like `ngShow = false` this way?

Comment: My guess is it's a poor choice of variable names. Not enough code context shown to understand anything from just that snippet

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Very unclear

Answer (score 0):

The question you can ask *us* can be paraphrased as:

> Does setting `ngIf` on `this` for a directive's controller do anything special?

The answer is: **no**. Here's proof:

```js
var $document = $(document);

angular.module("app", [])
  .directive("myElement", function() {
    return {
      template: "<strong>my directive content</strong>",
      controller: function elementCtrl($scope, $element) {
        var ct = this;
          $document.on('click', function() {
            ct.ngIf = false;
          });
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  MyElement = <my-element></my-element>
</div>
```

You have not provided a full, minimal repro, so I have to come up with one of my own. I think you would need something like this to make it do anything at all:

```js
var $document = $(document);

angular.module("app", [])
  .directive("myElement", function() {
    return {
      template: "<strong>Content: <ng-transclude ng-if='vm.ngIf'></ng-transclude></strong>",
      transclude: true,
      controllerAs: "vm",
      controller: function elementCtrl($scope, $element) {
        var ct = this;
        ct.ngIf = true;
        $document.on("click", function() {
          $scope.$apply(function() { ct.ngIf = false; });
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  MyElement = <my-element>Transcluded content.</my-element>
  <br>Click in the document to set ngIf false...
</div>
```

Quite a few extra things were needed (most notably transclusion and `$scope.$apply`) to demo a somewhat useful scenario. And even then **`ngIf` is nothing more than a poorly named property on the controller instance**. Nothing special. You could rename it as you like and nothing would change.

There is *no* Angular magic happening if you name a controller property "ngIf".

---

The question you cannot ask *us* is: *why* did the author do this? You'd have to ask the author.

PS. No offense, but I'd take the author's explanation with a grain of salt. Even from the small snippet of code you posted, there are quite a few red flags: custom jQuery event handlers inside a controller (on `$document`, which is probably `$(document)` (?), of all things), missing `$apply` calls, and variables with highly confusing names.